# How to change the font size of mat-step's label?

Tags: html, angular, font-size

Can't seem to change it using style= and css. Also here is my attached code

```
<div class="statusbar">
    <mat-horizontal-stepper linear >
            <mat-step label="One"  [completed]="false"></mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Two"  [completed]="false" [editable]="false"></mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Three"[completed]="false" [editable]="false"></mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Four"[completed]="false" [editable]="false"></mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Five"[completed]="false" [editable]="false"></mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Six"[completed]="false" [editable]="false"></mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Seven"[completed]="false" [editable]="false"></mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Eight"[completed]="false" [editable]="false"></mat-step>  
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>                                                            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 - Add `ViewEncapsulation.None` in component decorator.

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Step 2 - Add custom CSS.

```
.mat-step-header .mat-step-label .mat-step-text-label {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: red;
}
```

**Result -**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to use ViewEncapsulation.None or ng-deep, so I have another approach:
In HTML I change the label via template.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear >
    <mat-step [completed]="false">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>
            <label class="stepper-label">One</label>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

I add some CSS:

```
.stepper-label {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Finished.

Answer (score -2):

For me, this always works:

```
::ng-deep .mat-step-text-label {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```